# Displaying information within an infobox in Bing Maps

Tags: html, bing, markers, polygons

I am using Bing maps to display markers on the map.

I am able to display an infobox on the over of this markers.
Now my infobox contains a summary which is display somewhat like this

```
var pinInfoboxOptions = { 
     width: 300,
     height: sumxi,
     description: summ,
     visible:true
};
```

Now i am able to display the inbox where the description has the full information about the marker.
If i am to add a link by using the infoboxoptions actions then the infobox does not get displayed. please Help

```
var pinInfoboxOptions = { 
    width: 300,
    height: sumxi,
    description: summ,
    actions:[{label:'test1',eventHandler: testEvent1}],
    visible:true
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a link then you need to use the infobox option htmlContent, this is the example from the SDK docs:

```
var infoboxOptions = {width :200, 
height :100, showCloseButton: true, 
zIndex: 0, offset:new 
Microsoft.Maps.Point(10,0), 
showPointer: true, 
htmlContent:'Custom HTML'};
```

Based on the q's edit, the title click handler will probably do the job:
Again from the doc:

> '**titleClickHandler string**' The name of the function to call when
>   the title of the info box is clicked. If this property is set, the
>   title of the info box is  displayed as a link.'

Comment: Not eactly.. i want to add a link 'test1', but it does not redirect me to another page, it takes me to another Javascript function